# When I used assignment, the debug results show that the assignment failed

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
LinkNode* Result = ResultNode; 
DeleteLinkNode(ResultNode);
return Result;
```

/*when return the value of Result is "  Result  0x014adf98 {val=0xdddddddd next=0xdddddddd {val=??? next=??? p=??? } "
But when i create Result it's value is correct
*/

```
void Haff::DeleteLinkNode(LinkNode* temp) {
if (temp->next == NULL) {
    Pre(temp)->next = NULL;
    delete temp;
    return;
}
else {
    Pre(temp)->next = temp->next;
    delete temp;
}}

LinkNode* Haff::Pre(LinkNode* temp) {
LinkNode* move = LinkRoot->next;
while (move!=NULL) {
    if (move->next == temp) {
        return move;
    }
    move = move->next;
}
return NULL;
}
```

The URL of full code is below.
[Full Code](https://github.com/wangxinshuo426/Practice/blob/master/VisualStudio/Haff/Haff/%E6%BA%90.cpp)

Comment: Your two branches in `DeleteLinkNode` are identical. Both set `Pre(temp)->next = temp->next`, both `delete temp`, and both return.

Comment: In C, when you `free(ptr)`, the value of `ptr` becomes indeterminate. I assume the same holds for `delete` in C++, in which case `DeleteLinkNode(Result); return Result;` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Linking to a URL in a question is a no-no.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking